# try except inside try except

Tags: python, exception

Is the usage of `try...except` below correct? If not, what do I have to change?

```python
try:
    name_file = input('Welcome user, enter the name of the file to be opened: ')
    file = open('../' + name_file, 'r')
    # print(file.readlines(), end=' ')
except FileNotFoundError as err:
    print('File not found :(')
else:
    try:
        res = int(input('Which representation do you want to use? [1] Adjacency List - [2] Adjacency matrix'))
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Invalid option')
```

Comment: Are you facing any problem with this code ?

Comment: It's technically valid. But if you continue along this way you'll get deeply nested in try/except/else, which makes for unreadable code. Normally you would just let the exception stop the script.

Comment: the code is running with no error, i just want to know if it´s syntax is right

Answer (score 1):

This is correct syntax for try-except-else and will execute as needed if a user enters a non-int value for the second prompt. However, if a different number is entered, the ValueError will not be thrown.

```
  try:
    # Some Code
except:
    # Executed if error in the
    # try block
else:
    # execute if no exception
finally:
    # Some code .....(always executed)
```

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/#:~:text=Else%20Clause%20In%20python%2C%20you%20can%20also%20use,the%20try%20clause%20does%20not%20raise%20an%20exception.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/#:%7E:text=Else%20Clause%20In%20python%2C%20you%20can%20also%20use,the%20try%20clause%20does%20not%20raise%20an%20exception.)